# Parse JSON output with JQ

Tags: json, jq

Lets say I have an I/P json file as below. And I want to extract the O/P in a CSV format with the below fields. Specifically, I want to get the value of the key "Gamma" in the o/p if the key "Gamma" exists in "tags" map. If the key doesn't exists, it should just print a NULL value. The expected o/p is below.

```
generated_time,platform,id,,
2021-09-09:12:03:12,earth,2eeee67748,Ray,2021-08-25 09:41:06
2021-09-09:12:03:12,sun,xxxxx12334,NULL,2021-08-25 10:11:31
```

```
[
  { 
    "generated_time": "generated_time",
    "platform": "platform",
    "id": "id"
  },
    {
    "generated_time": "2021-09-09:12:03:12",
    "platform": "earth",
    "id": "2eeee67748",
    "tags": {
      "app": "map",
      "Gamma": "Ray",
      "null": [
        "allow-all-humans"
      ]
          },
    "created": "2021-08-25 09:41:06"
  },
   { 
    "generated_time": "2021-09-09:12:03:12",
    "platform": "sun",
    "id": "xxxxx12334",
    "tags": {
      "component": "machine",
      "environment": "hot",
      "null": [
        "aallow-all-humans"
      ]
    },
    "created": "2021-08-25 10:11:31"
   }
]
```

Comment: sounds easy, what's the problem?

Comment: I can get the simple one using jq -r '.[] | [.generated_time,.platform,.id,.created,.tags.Gamma] | join(",")' but looking for efficient way to get an explicit NULL

Comment: Why is the first object different? Do you want to exclude that one from the result?

Comment: I would just print nothing for the first object since it doesn't have the tags map.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, do you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 1):

`jq` has a [builtin](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) `@csv` which renders an array

> as CSV with double quotes for strings, and quotes escaped by repetition.

If the additional quoting (as compared to your expected output) isn't an issue, the following

```
jq --raw-output '
  
  # produce an array for each element in the input array
  .[] | [
    
    # containing the first three columns unchanged
    .generated_time, .platform, .id,
    
    # if the input element has a field named "tags"
    if has("tags")
    
    # then add two more columns and replace an inexistant Gamma with "NULL"
    then (.tags.Gamma // "NULL", .created)
    
    # otherwise add two empty columns instead
    else (null, null) end
    
  # and convert the array into CSV format
  ] | @csv
  
' input.json
```

will produce

```
"generated_time","platform","id",,
"2021-09-09:12:03:12","earth","2eeee67748","Ray","2021-08-25 09:41:06"
"2021-09-09:12:03:12","sun","xxxxx12334","NULL","2021-08-25 10:11:31"
```